# Scrape data from Apex which created with PL/SQL dynamic content?

Tags: html, plsql, web-scraping, oracle-apex

I have used PL/SQL dynamic content for creating a report. I need to add functionality to scrape (take data) from this HTML. Moreover, I have SQL which returns data.

How can I do this with APEX region PL/SQL dynamic content?

PL/SQL code for creating HTML tags with data:

```
declare     
  l_sql varchar2(2000) := test.function(92500, 2017, 2, 114); --return which select when we dynamical execute this select it will return data

  l_columns varchar2(2000) := test.test_function_dynamic_columns_name(92500, 2017, 2, 114);
  l_vc_arr2 APEX_APPLICATION_GLOBAL.VC_ARR2;

  v_tableclob clob := '<table summary="" class="a-IRR-table" id="2212903112260009" role="presentation">';
  v_rowclob clob;
  v_rowclob_1 clob;
begin   
  l_vc_arr2 := APEX_UTIL.STRING_TO_TABLE(l_columns);
  v_tableclob := v_tableclob||'<tr>'; 
  v_tableclob := v_tableclob ||'<th class="a-IRR-header">';
  v_tableclob := v_tableclob ||REPLACE(REPLACE(l_columns,'"',' '),':','</th><th class="a-IRR-header">');
  v_tableclob := v_tableclob ||'</th></tr>';

  FOR z IN 1..l_vc_arr2.count LOOP
    if l_vc_arr2(z) = '"SUM"' then
       v_rowclob := v_rowclob ||'<td class="summation">''||t.'||l_vc_arr2(z)||'||''</td>';
       v_rowclob_1 := v_rowclob_1 || '<td id="total_sum"></td>';
    else
       v_rowclob := v_rowclob ||'<td>''||t.'||l_vc_arr2(z)||'||''</td>';
       v_rowclob_1 := v_rowclob_1 ||  '<td></td>';
    end if;
  end loop;

  execute immediate 
   ' 
    declare 
    begin 
      htp.p('''||v_tableclob||''');

      for t in ('||l_sql||') loop
        htp.p(''<tr>'||v_rowclob||'</tr>'');
      end loop;

      htp.p(''<tr>'');
      htp.p('''|| v_rowclob_1 ||''');
      htp.p(''</tr>'');
      htp.p(''</table>'');   
    end;'; 

end;
```

Comment: Where is your code? Which functionality do you need to add?

Comment: @Dmitry I have added code for creating html

Comment: Typically scraping is only the last resort, when you don't have any access to the data source. Why would you build a system that requires it?

Comment: You generated the report, so you already have access to all the data. Why do you need to scrape it off the page afterward?